# I need to hide a div until Vimeo video is finished. How do I do that?

Tags: jquery, api, events, vimeo

I have site that has a Vimeo video where the client wants to hide a div, which contains a form link, until the video has finished. I saw on the Vimeo API Playground that there is a "Finish" event listener, but I have never messed with Vimeo before. I have a jquery call to hide or show the Div which I would run once the Vimeo finish event is declared. But how do I setup JQuery/Javascript to listen for that event?

Sorry, I am sure this is simple but I am a Vimeo novice. I currently have the Vimeo video hard coded into the HTML as an iframe within a div.

Thanks for any examples you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the froogaloop framework from http://vimeo.com/api/docs/downloads.Include the minified javascript library in your page and hook the finish events with you player and run the jQuery show/hide code inside the 'finish' event handler.

See an example here
http://player.vimeo.com/playground

Comment: Thanks Jason. I saw that and loaded in onto a testing site so I can play with it. I am playing with it now, but it is stretching my skill set. LOL.

Comment: If you can provide whatever you have developed so far(html and javascript),  I will try to help.

Comment: can you tell me, does http://player.vimeo.com/playground working now? it seems not working

Comment: Anyway you can provide an example of some code showing a jquery event firing on finish? Thanks!