# How to hide title when video is played?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, vimeo

I have put my own custom title absolutely positioned over the top of an Vimeo video embed (you can see the dev site here http://ourcityourstory.com/dev/). When I click on the Vimeo video I want the title absolutely positioned over it to hide.

How do I accomplish this? None of the JS I'm writing is working.

Here is my non-working code:

```
$(document).click({namespace: this}, function (e) {
    var t = e.data.namespace;

    if ($(e.target).parents("#video-slider-wrapper iframe").length > 0 || $(e.target).is($("#video-slider-wrapper iframe"))) {
        $("#episode h1").hide();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**: pimvdb's example listed below does exactly what I need my page to do — however, I keep getting the error "$f is not defined" on my page.

Comment: Can you show anyone of those non-working js ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911019/i-need-to-hide-a-div-until-vimeo-video-is-finished-how-do-i-do-that) is very similar to your problem. By the way, I've just tried to hide it with JQuery `hide()` and it worked. I think what you fail to explain is that you need help handling the `play event`

Comment: When the video starts playing I need to be able to .hide() the h1.

Comment: This is completely unnecessary: `.is($("#video-slider-wrapper iframe"))` Should be: `.is("#video-slider-wrapper iframe")`, since you only have to pass a selector. And `$(e.target).parents("#video-slider-wrapper iframe")` could be: `$("#video-slider-wrapper").has('iframe').size()`. You should also cache `$('#video-slider-wrapper')` within your `$.ready()` using `var $videowrap = $('#video-slider-wrapper')` (name not important, use `var` so it's local) and then reuse it where you have it above. `id` selectors are fairly fast, it's generic selectors like `iframe` which start to drag down speed.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the Vimeo API? I altered an example from the docs that works: http://jsfiddle.net/HfwWY/349/.

Comment: Looking at that `e.target` again, I think that could be: `$videowrap.has(e.target).size()`. Or something to that effect. I've gotten in the happen of appending jQuery references with a `$var`, so I can easily identify them.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: The whole handler is in fact unnecessary, since the click event won't fire on cross-domain iframes :)

Comment: @pimvdb - Right, valid point. Still though, good habits are good habits...

Comment: @pimvdb, your js fiddle example works perfectly. On my page, however, I keep getting the error "$f is not defined".

Comment: I think you have to include the API (http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js).

Comment: @pimvdb THANK YOU! Would you please add your answer below so I can give you proper credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `click` handler does not work because the iframe is cross-domain. However, you can use the [dedicated Vimeo API](http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js) to add a listener when the `play` event is fired:

```
var player = $f( $('#player1').get(0) );

player.addEvent('play', function() {
  $("h1").hide();
});
```

​